# Spinnaker Support for App ELB in AWS

Tags: spinnaker

Am facing 2 issues with Spinnaker new installation.

1. I could not see my Application load balancers listed in dropdown of load balancers tab while creating pipeline. We are currently using only app. load balancers in our current set up. I tried editing the JSON file of pipeline with below config and it didn't work. I verfied it by checking the ASG created in my AWS account and checked if there is any ELB/Target group associated but I couldn't see any. 
   "targetGroups": [
   "TG-APP-ELB-NAME-DEV"
   ],
   Hence, I would like to confirm how I can get support of App. ELB into Spinnaker installation and how to use it.
2. Also I have an ami search issue found.My current set up briefing is below.

One managing account - prod where my spinnaker ec2 is running & my prod application instances are running
Two managed accounts - dev & test where my application test instances are running.

When I create a new AMI in my dev AWS account and am trying to search the newly created AMI from my Spinnaker and it failed with error that it couldn't search the AMI first. Then I shared my AMI in dev to prod after which it was able to search it but failed with UnAuthorized error

Please help me clarify
1. If sharing is required for any new AMI from dev -> Prod or our spinnakerManaged role would take care of permissions
2. How to fix this problem and create AMI successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding #1, have you created the App Load Balancer through the Spinnaker UI or directly through AWS?
If it is the former, then make sure it follows the naming convention agreed by Spinnaker (I believe the balancer name should start with the app name)

Comment: I have created through AWS. Problem is in Spinnaker am not seeing it in drop down when I try to assign my ServerGroup to this ELB. Also, I'm not seeing an ELB type under LoadBalancer section to say this is an App ELB or Classic ELB.  Could you pls let me know how we can create an App. ELB in AWS and how to map an existing App ELB to servergroup. Is there an option to bypass the naming convention?

Comment: Thanks for insights.